# .NET 5.0: Build a project in a multi-project solution

Tags: c#, .net-core, build, .net-5

My solution contains multiple projects (e.g., .NET Console app, ASP.NET Web application, Python scripts, unit tests, and etc.). At points, I'm interested in building a specific project without compiling the others. For instance, build the console app without compiling the web app.

I tried the following:

```
dotnet build .\console_app.csproj
```

However, this builds all the projects in the solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: It shouldn't build everything - it should only build that project *and the other projects it depends on* (transitively). For example, if there's another project that `console_app` doesn't depend on (even transitively) that is currently broken, then building `console_app.csproj` shouldn't fail due to that.

Comment: If you believe you have a counter-example, it would be helpful to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you. My console app depends on other .NET projects in the solution hence all are build. I believe a bad dependency architecture on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: `Temporarily` disable those projects

You can temporarily remove the others from the build configuration see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-exclude-projects-from-a-build?view=vs-2019#to-temporarily-remove-a-project-from-the-active-solution-configuration),

1. To temporarily remove a project from the active solution
   configuration On the menu bar, choose `Build > Configuration Manager`.
2. In the `Project contexts table`, locate the project you want to
   exclude from the build.
3. In the `Build column` for the project, clear the check box.
4. Choose the `Close button`, and then rebuild the solution. You may have to exit and restart VS.

---

### Option 2: Create a NEW Build Configuration

> I like/recommend this because your don't loose your old build, and with the click of a button [its very easy to SWITCH between the two Build/Solution Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-exclude-projects-from-a-build?view=vs-2019#to-create-a-solution-configuration-that-excludes-a-project).

1. To create a solution configuration that excludes a project
   On the menu bar, choose `Build > Configuration Manager`.
2. In the `Active solution configuration list`, choose `<New>`.
3. In the `Name box`, enter a name for the solution configuration.
4. In the Copy settings from list, choose the solution configuration on which you want to base the new configuration (for example, `Debug`), and then choose the OK button.
5. In the `Configuration Manager` dialog box, clear the check box in the Build column for the project that you want to exclude, and then choose the Close button.
6. On the `Standard toolbar`, verify that the new solution configuration is the active configuration in the Solution Configurations box.
7. On the menu bar, choose `Build > Rebuild Solution`.